Is this question about water genasi actually ambiguous?
I was surprised to see that this question: What exactly would destroy water do to a water genasi? has been closed for eleven hours as "needs details or clarity".  There's a comment from a moderator that says: "It's important to note that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?"
I had thought that we resolved this issue in 2021 with Revisit III: Don’t Guess the System policy.  I liked the quote from the accepted answer:

By saying "we cannot answer your question until you learn how to use tags, even though everyone knows what system you're playing", we are putting problem solving in the back seat and setting site mechanics as our primary objective for new users. We should never tell a new user that our problem with their lack of tags or explicit forthrightness about the system is more important than the problem they bring to the table. But that is exactly what we are doing when we know what they are talking about but artificially hold up the problem solving process because they didn't explicitly state what system they are playing.

But somehow we have five people who voted to close this question, and a moderator who appears to agree with them.  (And seven people upvoted the comment!)  Are there really that many RPGs that have a spell called "Create Or Destroy Water" and a playable Water Genasi race?
I thought this might be a confusion with 5e-2024 (and that we might just be doing a really bad job of communicating "we know it's 5e but you have to tell us which version of 5e"), but checking this article it looks like there are only ten species in 5e-2024 so far and none of them are water genasi.  Similarly, there does not appear to be a spell called create or destroy water in 3.5e.

You sure about the spell not existing in earlier editions? Looks like destroy water spells have existed in 1E, 2E, 3E and 5E. And I know for a fact that water genasi were playable in 2E Planescape.


Are there really that many RPGs that have a spell called "Create Or Destroy Water" and a playable Water Genasi race?

I would argue that this question is not really pertinent. Here is a real big problem with the question: the situation that OP describes does not align with how the D&D 5e Create or Destroy Water spell works. Crucially, the question says:

I attacked an enemy using "Create or Destroy Water"

Yet the spell is not an attack, not meant as an attack, and is not described in any way as an attack.
For that matter, the genasi in D&D 5e also do not work as described in the question. That applies to both versions of the genasi in D&D 5e, for there are two different ones (one is legacy).
It is possible this uses some sort of house ruling in which case, it just means there is even more need for clarification.
At face value, we could figure out an answer for D&D 5e. But the answer would essentially say "the situation you describe cannot happen". Is such an answer even useful there? If we assume that OP does play D&D 5e, and that their DM did rule the way they did, then that is how it works in that group and in that session. If they have some sort of homebrew setting, then essentially the only real answer is "The custom setting and rules that the DM made works the way the DM has made them". Tautologically confirming that what happens does indeed happen.

It should be noted that you have quoted from the discussion post about repealing the policy, not the guidance post that replaced the policy which states:

We are not going to police closure of underspecified questions. Recall the two categories mentioned previously - questions that could be about anything, and questions that could be about one of some number of systems. The difference between these two things is not always going to be particularly clear. One user may think they have a questions narrowed down to two systems, and one user may think the question should be closed for "needs details or clarity". This second user is free to vote for closure on the question, and the community will work it out as we do with all questions that are put up for closure review.

Users can vote to close if they think a question is unclear for whatever reason. And you can vote to open if you think it’s clear enough.
My personal take on the question is that it needs details for reasons other than missing the system. I think we need to know a bit more about what happened and what OP is talking about in the question to get a really good answer for it. Sure, if it were open I could just write “in the dnd 5e rules that spell just doesn’t do that”, but that might not really be helpful since I’m assuming OP already knows that much, hence the question.

We should at least give the correct close reason
Right now, the top question comment says:

Welcome to the site! Please take the tour when you get the chance. It's important to note that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?

followed by seven comments arguing about whether the spell Create Or Destroy water exists in previous editions.  (It doesn't.  I cannot link to evidence here, because there does not exist a free-to-use list of all D&D 3.5e spells.)
This creates the impression that we've closed the question because we aren't able to figure out what edition OP is asking about.  But then, here in meta, everyone is arguing:

I would argue that this question [about which edition] is not really pertinent. Here is a real big problem with the question: the situation that OP describes does not align with how the D&D 5e Create or Destroy Water spell works.

If our top comment on the question was: "Hey, the only Create Or Destroy Water spell we know of is in D&D 5e and the spell can't be used for combat at all, are you playing in some sort of weird homebrew setting or do you actually want to know about 5e?", I would think that was perfectly fine.
But instead we have this stock answer about how we can't figure out the edition.  I think that's much less helpful.

The close reason is correct: it's at the top of the question and asks the asker to provide more details. Which they should do. You are talking about the first comment which asks for the game they play. It's relevant maybe it's some "clone" of D&D with similar setting and spells where their question does make sense. However, it might also be D&D 5e which makes the question require other details to resolve how exactly this situation arose. This is what the second comment asks for.
